# Setting Views frame to match another not working?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm very confused on what Is going on here. I set a view to match another because It plays the audio I need in the background here:

```
     @IBOutlet weak var playerView: YouTubePlayerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
    // plays in background but doesnt show video
    Djay.shared.youTubePlayer.frame = playerView.frame
    playerView = Djay.shared.youTubePlayer
// ... sets up player view like normal 
   playerView.delegate = self
    let playerVars = ["controls": "1", "playsinline": "1", "autohide": "1", "showinfo": "1", "autoplay": "1", "fs": "1", "rel": "0", "loop": "0", "enablejsapi": "1", "modestbranding": "1"]
    playerView.playerVars = playerVars as YouTubePlayerView.YouTubePlayerParameters
    playerView.loadVideoID("\(Djay.shared.songs[0].songId!)")
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appEnteredBackgound), name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)
    view.addSubview(activity)
    activity.center = playerView.center
    activity.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activity.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .gray
    activity.startAnimating()
```

Result of the above code:

Plays audio of video in background and foreground however video is no where to be seen. The activity indicator spins then is stopped when the player delegate's videodidload method is fired. Yet the player is not in view?

```
[![Pic of it not working][1]][1]
```

However when I remove the these lines :

```
     override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // plays in background but doesnt show video
   // Djay.shared.youTubePlayer.frame = playerView.frame
  //  playerView = Djay.shared.youTubePlayer
    // ... sets up player view like normal
```

I get the video playing on screen , but then audio does not play in background.

[image: video playing]

My solution is that I want to set up the view like I did in the first case ( where audio was playing correctly in the background) But I need to see the video on screen.

**In short**

How come the setting the frame to being identical Isnt working? What can I do to fix this issue.

note: youtubePlayerView is an extension of UIview. It has a web-view inside of it . If there is any more information you need please let me know , I tried to be as brief as possible.

Comment: Are you sure the player view is "not showing"? Your code is only showing one `playerView` ...

Comment: youtube player from djay.shared is the other playerview @DonMag

Comment: You're setting `playerView = Djay.shared.youTubePlayer` ... but your code doesn't show a 2nd instance.